# echo first row of data into page title

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of contacts and a search form the returns the contact searched for. All work fine as it should. But is it possible to show an instance of the first row only in a separate div or span  at top of page? I have seen this done in MS Access, is it possible in php? Here is my search query but I have no idea how to echo or show the first row only into a title or heading div.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people";
if( isset($_GET['search']) ){
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']));
$name2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlspecialchars($_GET['search2']));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE first_name ='$name' AND last_name= '$name2'";
}
$result = $con->query($sql);
?>

<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['people_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: of course it is, you just have to code it

Comment: Set a flag before you open the `while` loop to indicate that you're on the first row. Inside the loop check for that flag, if it's true then output the html to put the first row in the div you want it in, and set the flag to false. Otherwise, put the rows in the other div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just would do it like this (updated answer):

```
$tableData = [];
$divData = "";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  // empty tableData --> first row
  if (empty($tableData)) {
    // do your special for the first row here (div)
    $divData = "hello world! ".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'];
  }

  $tableData[] ="<tr>
    <td>".$row['people_id']."</td>
    <td>".$row['first_name']."</td>
    <td>".$row['last_name']."</td>
    <td>".$row['address']."</td>
    <td>".$row['contact']."</td>
        </tr>";    
}

echo "<div>".$divData."</div>";
echo "<table>";
echo implode("\n", $tableData);
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you Marco. But I may not have explained myself well. I want to keep the table intact that returned the search query and have the first row of that table echoed or duplicated in a div at the top of the page. Your example only returns one row from the query.

Comment: @terry would be nice if you mark the answer as correct, so everybody sees that the problem is solved.

Comment: My apologies I didn't realize I had not.